# How to compute the weight of each vertex in the generated clustering tree

Tags: clustering, vertex

In the documention of the "ClusteringTree", it is written that the result from ClusteringTree is a binary weighted tree, where the weight of each vertex indicates the distance between the two subtrees that have that vertex as root.
In the Example_Scope:

g = ClusteringTree[{0.1, 2.2, 3.4, 5.6, 8.9}]

Look at the distance between subclusters by looking at the VertexWeight.

AnnotationValue[g, VertexWeight]
{1.9511, 0, 0.31497, 0.274778, 0, 0, 0.292431, 0, 0}

Wouuld you please illustrate how the distances can be obtained? I supposed it is the Euclidian distance.